# bash function to find a directory recursively

Tags: bash, scripting, directory-structure

How can I write a bash-function that finds a specific parent directory. Here's my setup:

```
/home/user/dev/project1/branch1/deeply/nested/module/structure
```

The app-server used for devs is located at:

```
/home/user/dev/project1/branch1/apps/someappserver
```

I'd like to have a bash function that goes up recursively to the branch's root to quickly copy compiled modules to the appserver, run/stop the appserver, call specific maven goals etc.

Any ideas? Each branch has a maven pom.xml which contains exact information about the version

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
find_branch_root () {
    cwd=$PWD
    while [ ! -e "$cwd/pom.xml" ] && [ "x$cwd" != x/ ]; do
         cwd=`dirname "$cwd"`
    done
    echo "$cwd"
}
```

Peals off directories from the path until either root (/) is reached or "pom.xml" is found.

Comment: You can save a process by replacing `dirname "$cwd"` with `cwd=${cwd%/*}; cwd=${cwd:-/}`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a exported env var with a name like `PRJDIR` which has a value like `/home/user/dev/project1`. This env var can easily referenced by further scripts kike this:

```
stop-app
cp ${PRJDIR}/modules/* modules/*
start-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `while` loop that does `cd ..` unless/until it finds an appropriate file or directory, then does `cd` down into the new directory structure putting you in the correct place? Would that not work?

Comment: A function is asked for; doing a `cd` in a function changes the current directory in the calling shell as well, which is likely not what is wanted.

Comment: @Arcege The function could save and restore the cwd, and even `$OLDPWD` to be extra thorough.